# Real time notification using async servlet not working as needed

Tags: jsp, servlets, real-time

I need real time notification on a `jsp` page while the action occur in another page. So I decided using `async servlets`. What I have is 2 pages:

Page 1 and page 2. I have a button on page 1 in button click of page1 I should get notification on page 2. Please guide me. It should be server side page1 and page2 can be accessed from different users from different locations.

I have referred the link : [TUTORIAL](http://www.javabeat.net/asynchronous-servlet-servlet-3-0/)

I have implemented this. But it only updating a single page with request response methods

How can I modify the same tutorial to make as my desired way.

Here it is just calling `servlet` on button click as:

```
function handleAjaxBtn1(){

  var xmlhrObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhrObj.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/asyncHello?type=1&counter="+counter1, true);
  counter1++;
  xmlhrObj.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhrObj.readyState == 4 && xmlhrObj.status == 200){
      var div1 = document.getElementById("req1Response");
      div1.innerHTML = xmlhrObj.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhrObj.send();

}
```

It will occur in a single page and in page load counter value is set. It is just passing into it. It looks confusing because it handled with only one page.

I need notification on page2 on button click of first page I mean Real time notification.

Is there any tutorial just like [PRIMEFACES](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml) in `jsf`  for `jsp/servlet`?

Comment: What you're doing and what you need are two different things. Servlet Async options is to free container thread from long running requests so that requests don't wait in the queue. For real time notification you'll need push notification with Websockets or something like that. Look up STOMP server and client side implementations.

Comment: @11thdimension  thanks buddy. I am new to this that is why confused.  I want something like Primefaces. please check link above!!

Comment: @11thdimension can you suggest a link tutorial will be very helpful. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Primefaces is doing the same thing, it's using Comet for poling otherwise Websocket for push notification. If you're using Spring you can check Spring's implementation of Websocket if not try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Fi4vz6oUio

Comment: @11thdimension buddy I am not using any frame works. I am using default jsp/servlet making use of tomcat. not using any frameworks!!

Comment: Tomcat since 7 has Websocket implementation, see this example. https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774

Comment: @11thdimension mine is tomcat8. does it work for 8? getting error while compiling import not found!!

Comment: Yes it should, you'll have to add tomcat/lib/websocket-api.jar to your classpath, if you're working with Eclipse, you can just add tomcat 8 as server runtime under buildpath>libraries. I will try to post a working example in a answer today.

Comment: tomcat/lib/websocket-api.jar is not containing the metods as you imported as mentioned example so it throws error. Please update as an answer. it will be helpful!!